# Sending packets with Scapy within Python environment

Tags: python, scapy

I am playing around with Scapy and I want to use it within a Python script but sending packets seem to be a problem. Here is my code.

Scapy Shell:

```
send(IP(src="10.0.99.100",dst="10.1.99.100")/ICMP()/"Hello World")
```

This works fine and sends the packet.

Python script:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python

from scapy.all import sr1,IP,ICMP

p=sr1(IP(src="10.0.99.100",dst="10.1.99.100")/ICMP()/"Hello World")
```

This runs fine but when it tries to send the packet I get:

```
WARNING: No route found for IPv6 destination :: (no default route?)
Begin emission:
.Finished to send 1 packets.
....^C
Received 5 packets, got 0 answers, remaining 1 packets
```

Comment: What exactly is your question? It looks to me like everything is working fine.

Comment: In the scapy environment I get a output of "Sent 1 packets" and it works but with python it just starts receiving packets and not sending it

Answer (score 17):

When you run this in the Python environment you are using the `sr1` function. The `sr1` function will send a packet and then wait for an answer, keeping a count of received packets. See more here -

http://www.secdev.org/projects/scapy/doc/usage.html#send-and-receive-packets-sr

To get the behavior you desire, you need to use the `send` function, just like you did when using the Scapy shell.

```
#! /usr/bin/env python

from scapy.all import send, IP, ICMP

send(IP(src="10.0.99.100",dst="10.1.99.100")/ICMP()/"Hello World")
```